# Gromov hyperbolicity of Metric Spaces

Tags: gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

[Proof of lemma 2.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQedL.jpg)

Hi, I was doing some self reading on Gromov geometry and I have difficulty accepting the proof given above for lemma 2.4. While I can understand that $(x|z)\ge \max\{(x|w),(y|z)\}$, there is no assumption imposed whatsoever on  $(y|w)$. The last line of the proof seem to suggest that $(x|z)+(y|w)\ge (y|z)+(x|w)$ 1which may not be true for the reason stated above.

Is there something wrong with the proof above or am I missing something here?